# CSS Text Spacing inside a Div Block

Tags: css

How would I place my text slightly to the left so that it is consistent with the grab of the orange bar attached? If I do "Text-Align: Left" it moves too far to the left. Thank you for your help.

[image: image of what I am going for]

```
#orange-bar {
    width: 18%;
    height: 43px;
    position: left;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color:#FF6633;
    font-family:'LinotypeUniversW01-Bold 723691';
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 43px;}


<html>
<head>
<title>Instagram</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fast.fonts.com/jsapi/999aedb9-3bfd-4571-a6ad-   1d2b5e4de25f.js"></script>

<link href="/static/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <a href = '/instagram' id = 'header-name'></a>  
    <form method = 'post'>  
        <input onfocus="this.value=''" onblur="this.value='#tag search'" type = 'text'    name = 'tag' id = 'tag-search' value = '#tag search'></input>
    </form>
    <div>   
        <input type="submit" id = "submit">
    </div>      
    <div id = "header-bar"></div>
    <div id="orange-bar">#LOOKLAB</div>     
    <div id = "container">
```

Comment: We need your html code

Comment: And the CSS for the white bar

Comment: What is `position: left;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try padding:

```
#orange-bar {
    width: 18%;
    height: 43px;
    position: left;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color:#FF6633;
    font-family:'LinotypeUniversW01-Bold 723691';
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 43px;
}

#orange-bar p {
     padding-left:10px;   
}
```

Here is a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doodelicious/LnjQr/1/) to show you what it looks like.

You mentioned in response that the padding is adding to the width of the orange-bar div. This is because padding, margins and borders affect the width of the div it is applied to (from w3schools.com):

> Important: When you set the width and height properties of an element
>   with CSS, you just set the width and height of the content area. To
>   calculate the full size of an element, you must also add the padding,
>   borders and margins.

Another way to tackle this issue for you would be to apply the padding to another tag (such as a span, p, or nested div) that simply states a padded amount and not width).

For more information on how padding, border and margin affect content area, read up on the [Box Model article at w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Comment: but padding is making the orange div bar longer as well. I just want to move the text within the div.

Comment: I revised my answer above to explain how content area size is affected by padding, margin and borders.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the padding-left attribute for the element that you want to line up with the orange bar.

```
padding-left: 10px;
```

Comment: I just added the html code - it is very simple. @sergio I am not looking to recreate the white bar. All I want to do is move the text element to the some pixels to the right inside the orange bar div so that it is consistent with my screengrab.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: left;
```

is not a correct css property.
if I get your request right you can use padding as follow:

```
padding-left:5px;
```

if you have more than one div & want to arrange them all in left then you can use following css:

```
padding-left:5px; text-align:left;
```

and using position command is like this:

```
position: absolute; left:20px;
```

Comment: but padding is making my 'orange-bar' div longer as well. I just want to move the text within the div.